# Java Android Adding values to ArrayList

Tags: java, javascript, android, arraylist

I am trying to add values to arraylist in android application.

The problem that I am having is that the value is not being inserted in the array list.

Code Below:

```
for (var c=0; c < SelectedFavContacts.length; c++){

        if (SelectedFavContacts[c] !== undefined) {

            var SelectedContact = document.getElementById(SelectedFavContacts[c]).getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;

            for( i = 0 ; i < arrayKeys.length; i++ )
            {
                var records =  myContacts[arrayKeys[i]];

                for(var r_key in records) {

                    if (SelectedContact == records[r_key].name) {

                        if (typeof FavContacts[looper] == 'undefined')
                        {
                            FavContacts[looper] = new Array();
                        }

                        FavContacts[looper].push({"name":records[r_key].name, "pNumber": records[r_key].pNumber, "img": records[r_key].img} );
                        looper++;

                        alert(records[r_key].name); //displaying successfully the name successfully;

                        window.MainActivity.SetFavSettings(records[r_key].name, records[r_key].pNumber, records[r_key].img);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private List<String> listContactName  = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> listContactNo  = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> listFavImg = new ArrayList<String>();

@JavascriptInterface
public void SetFavSettings(String FavContactName, String FavContactNo, String FavImg){

    listContactName.add(FavContactName);
    listContactNo.add(FavContactNo);
    listFavImg.add(FavImg);

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListenera = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              switch (which){
              case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                  finish();
                  break;

              case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                  break;
              }
          }
      };

      // favContactName is being displayed. 
      //listContactName.get(0) = Nothing
      // listContactName.size() = nothing
      AlertDialog.Builder buildera = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
      buildera.setMessage("entered " + FavContactName + " checking :)) = " + listContactName.get(0) + " list size =  " + listContactName.size()).setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListenera)
      .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListenera).show();
}
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong please

Comment: `listContactName.get(0) = Nothing` can happen if parameter you passed is blank..but how can `listContactName.size() = nothing` happen ? It should give you atleast zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have an error in the first test condition operator

```
if (SelectedFavContacts[c] !== undefined)
```

I think it's != and not !==